# Если значение не равно

Tags: jquery

Есть список городов, например 30 штук.

Нужно при отправке формы сделать проверку на *jquery*, что был указан один из 30 городов, заданных ранее.

Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? И в вопросе не указаны ни HTML, ни текущий JS.

Comment: Поставил минус, т.к. вопрос подразумевает ответ - можно! Сформулируйте вопрос иначе, опишите где и как вы задаете города "ранее"

Comment: А текст "Как это можно осуществить?" не чего вам не говорит?

Comment: Ответ "Взять и осуществить" вам в голову, верно, не пришел? В чем проблема - не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто вставьте в форму select такого вида:

```
<select name='city' required>
    <option>Москва</option>
    <option>Санкт-Петербург</option>
    <option>Екатеринбург</option>
    <option>Новосибирск</option>
    <option>... и т.д.</option>
</select>
```

Этим приемом вы обеспечите то, что всегда будет выбран один из нужных вам городов

Comment: Спасибо и действительно.